# I have an error: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner, what is wrong?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Kindly This is my code below, and I am pasting the error messages underneath: 
I am trying to use `setOnItemClickListener` on the spinner, is it permissible?

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int index, long arg3) {
    if (quantity[index]=="Meter" ){
        s1="Meter";
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "convert from meter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
}

   });

convertto.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg, View v1, int index1, long arg4)
    {
        if ((quantity[index1]=="Meter") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Meter")))
        {
            Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to meter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            var2=var1;
            lresult.setText("" + var2);
        }
    }      
});

}

}
```

and here are the errors

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.a2zunitconverter.miniproject/com.a2zunitconverter.miniproject.lenght}: java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemClickListener(Spinner.java:102)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at com.a2zunitconverter.miniproject.lenght.onCreate(lenght.java:31)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner

Comment: This happens when you copy listView.setOnItemClicklistener to Spinner, The spinner takes it as you intend do something with that, weird

Answer (score 251):

See the first line of your logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
```

`setOnItemClickListener` cannot be used with a `Spinner`. Use `setOnItemSelectedListener` instead.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener

Comment: @alex i understand . but why did android studio show setOnItemClickListener  option in auto complete , is it normal behavior , bug or some thing else.

Comment: why? it's decalred as Spinner valid method in documentataion https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Comment: What if we need to select an item again? This method will not work for the same selection.

Answer (score 60):

As @Alex very well said, you have to use

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Or if you are using ButterKnife:

```
@OnItemSelected(R.id.spinner)
public void onSpinnerItemSelected(int index){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 26):

## Kotlin:

```
spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
        print("onItemSelected position = $position id = $id")
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

    }
}
```

I wrote it because inline creating object from the interface is different.

Answer (score 11):

Simply change your implementation form `setOnItemClickListener` to `setOnItemSelectedListener`. Your code should work fine afterwards without error.

**Java:**

```
convertto.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

**Kotlin:**

```
convertto.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {

    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Change this

```
 convertto.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg, View v1, int index1, long arg4)
    {
         if ((quantity[index1]=="Meter") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Meter")))
        {

        Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to meter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        var2=var1;
        lresult.setText("" + var2);
        }

    }

   });
```

to onItemSelectedListener,

```
 convertto.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
         if ((quantity[index1]=="Meter") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Meter")))
        {

        Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to meter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        var2=var1;
        lresult.setText("" + var2);
        }


    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

It looks like you cannot use itemClickListener in your Spinner,

Here is the error line which explains it,

```
07-04 09:48:39.912: E/AndroidRuntime(694): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
```

Answer (score 5):

Solved by

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int  
 i, long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```