# Why can OnItemClickListener not work with a Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, onitemclick, onitemselectedlistener

I want to know if there is a specific reason why you cannot use `OnItemClickListener` with a spinner in Android? Looking through older posts ( [setOnItemClickListener Not Works with Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064498/setonitemclicklistener-not-works-with-spinner) and [I have an error: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner, what is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322642/i-have-an-error-setonitemclicklistener-cannot-be-used-with-a-spinner-what-is-w)) it seems as though people don't even bother with `OnItemClickListener` and rather go straight for `OnItemSelectedListener`. Why does Eclipse give `OnItemClickListener` as an option for a spinner if it can never work?

**Some context**- I'm not really too bothered by which method I use. As soon as the user selects an item from the spinner, I want to make a second spinner visible and populate it from the database based on the option selected in the first spinner. Now when I use `OnItemSelectedListener`, the second spinner is immediately set to visible. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: On question about Eclipse, I don't know; on what seems to be a programming issue about your two spinners, you might want to add some details and some code.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does Eclipse give OnItemClickListener as an option for a spinner if it can never work?

Because everything extending `AdapterView` has `setOnItemClickListener()`. Just because some subclasses ignore it does not mean that the setter magically disappears.

> Is there a workaround for this?

There is no workaround, because there is no problem, because it is doing exactly what you say you want to have happen ("I want to make a second spinner visible and populate it from the database based on the option selected in the first spinner"). A `Spinner` **always has a selection** if there is data to select from. Hence, your second `Spinner` should always be visible, since it is "based on the option selected in the first spinner", and there will **always be** an "option selected in the first spinner".

It sounds like what you *really* want is to only have the second `Spinner` visible for specific selections in the first `Spinner`, where you set up the first `Spinner` where there is some selection that, in business terms if not technical terms, means "no selection". You are welcome to do this, but then you will have to implement the logic to handle this, only showing the second `Spinner` when an appropriate value is selected in the first `Spinner`.

Comment: I am having a Spinner issue with onItemClick() in a RecyclerView list here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312851/fix-onitemclick-for-recyclerview  I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas you have.