# Android Spinner not responding to clicks, does not close and OnItemSelectedListener does not fire off

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, kotlin, anko

I am developing an app in Kotlin (if you don't know about kotlin I am sure you can still help with your Android/Java experience)

**Details:**

I have a Spinner in there my app.Though it is not responding to clicks once it pops up and even shows some weird views. And because of that the OnItemSelected listener is never fired either.

I start the method to update the spinner from an AsyncRealm call.

**Here's the code:**

This whole function runs, the spinner is not null, after attaching the listener, it is no longer null either (when debugging).

```
    private fun updateCategorySpinner(result: MutableList<Category>) {
        info("updateCategorySpinner")
        val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(ctx, R.layout.spinner_item, result.map{ it.category })
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item)
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        categorySpinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
        info("updateCategorySpinner done")
    }
```

**result.map{..} creates a MutableList with Category names.**

**Problem:**

I have no idea why there are those arrows, but no matter what layout I
use (even if just a simple TextView) they are there

What am I missing here?

Disabling the listener doesn't help.

Attaching the listener with Anko doesn't help.

The listener fires once when it is initialized, that's it.

Once the dropdown opens it is completely stuck.

I am creating my views with Anko.

The `R.layout.spinner-item` is just a `<Textview>`.

```
class AddTodoFragmentUi:AnkoComponent<ViewGroup>,AnkoLogger {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<ViewGroup>): View {
        val editTextTheme = R.style.Widget_AppCompat_EditText

        return with(ui){
            verticalLayout {
                info("inVerticalLayout")
                verticalPadding =dip(15)
                gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                editText(editTextTheme){
                    id = R.id.txt_todo_desc
                    hintResource = R.string.txt_todo_desc_hint
                    width = matchParent

                }
                spinner(R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Spinner){
                    id= R.id.spinner_todo_category
                    prompt = "Select a Category"
                }
                button{
                    id = R.id.btn_add_todo
                    textResource = R.string.btn_add_todo
                    width = matchParent

                }
                button{
                    id = R.id.btn_del_todo
                    textResource = R.string.btn_del_todo
                    width = matchParent
                    visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                }

            }.applyRecursively {view -> when(view){
                is EditText -> view.textSize = 20f
                is Button -> view.textSize = 30f
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

image:

[image: Spinner Dropped-down]

Comment: (`I am developing an app in Kotlin (very readable so even if you don't know it` a strong statement given the code you present isn't commented - or did the `it` refer to _Kotlin_, not your application.)

Comment: it referred to Kotlin indeed. I ddidn't give the link to the whole app, plus the code I presented is pretty explanatory. It's all just Android SDK calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the issue of non-responsiveness was with setting up the Widget_app_compact spinner theme.

```
 spinner(R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Spinner){
                    id= R.id.spinner_todo_category
                    prompt = "Select a Category"
```

Removing it solves the problem.

Don't lose two days as I did on this, please :D.